# Каким образом можно отменить уже загруженный коммит?

Tags: github

Каким образом можно отменить уже загруженный коммит с его изменениями на удаленный репозиторий? В моем случае - это последний коммит.
Этим последним коммитом является - merge. git revert в данном случае - не работает!

Comment: вы уже на гитхаб этот коммит кинули?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать get reset на определённое состояние, на коммит до вашего коммита, а потом сделать git push - - force, но будьте осторожны, force сотрёт все коммиты после того на который вы ресетнулись

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте откатить коммит:

```
git revert { commit_id }
```

ID коммита вводить без {}.

Comment: error: commit ae2f617b8cd9c4f8eb9df284d28339e1bc1b83fe is a merge but no -m opti                                                                                                    on was given.
fatal: revert failed

А что если коммит является мерджем?

Comment: Кажется я нашел решение вашего вопроса по этой ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch